# Check that a slug is present in the get_terms request

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-taxonomy, query

I want to give users the ability to create various custom post from the frontend, but depending on the assigned taxonomy, return the custom post form linked to it. So after having obtained the selected taxonomy, it is impossible for me to check if it exists in the get_terms() request.
I thougt it was because the in_array() function doesn't do a great job when it is about multidimensional array. so I searched and find here a way to make another function that overcome that problem, but it stil doesn't work.

 
Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $cptTax = $_GET['choosetax'];

$tax1List = get_terms([
                        'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                    ]);

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if( in_array_r($cptTax, $tax1List, false)): ?>
<form action="action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I checked the $tax1List variable with a var_dump() and the slug is there... but the function return false.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if a term with a specific slug exists in the database, then you can use [`term_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_exists/). E.g.

```php
<?php if ( term_exists( $cptTax, 'tax1' ) ) : ?>
    Your form here.
<?php endif; ?>
```

But if you do meant to check if the term is in a specific terms array, then you can use [`wp_list_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_filter/) like so:

```php
<?php
$found_terms = wp_list_filter( $tax1List, array( // set one or more conditions
    'slug' => $cptTax,
) );

if ( ! empty( $found_terms ) ) : ?>
    Your form here.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or you could instead use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to use your own filter function, like this:

```php
$found_terms = array_filter( $tax1List, function ( $term ) use ( $cptTax ) {
    return ( $cptTax === $term->slug ); // here, set your own custom logic
} );

if ( ! empty( $found_terms ) ) : ?>
    Your form here.
<?php endif; ?>
```

And just so you know, your custom function (`in_array_r()`) returned false because [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) by default returns an array of **objects** where each is an instance of the [`WP_Term` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/). So basically, the `if` in your function would need a condition that looks like `( is_object( $item ) && $needle === $item->slug )`. However, for simple filtering, I would use the `wp_list_filter()` above.